# How to use Xamarin without the IDE?

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin

I want to write an iOS app in C# with Xamarin and MonoTouch. I want to use Vim and Z shell instead of Xamarin Studio. However, I can't find much documentation on how to build from the command-line.

The documentation for the `mtouch` command says you have to pass an assembly as an argument, but how do I create that assembly?

Comment: Does anything on this page help you? http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/build_process EDIT: Or here: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/mtouch

Answer (score 5):

The command line compilers that Mono provides are `mcs`, `gmcs`, and `dmcs`. For Mono 2.10.x and earlier, these are for C# 1.0, C# 2.0, and C# 4.0, respectively; for Mono 3.0.x, `mcs` defaults to the most recent version, and you have to select earlier language/runtime versions with the `-langversion` and `-sdk` options. The `dmcs` and `gmcs` commands in 3.0.x are scripts that call `mcs` with the appropriate `-sdk` option.

I am not sufficiently familiar with Xamarin.iOS to know how the libraries are laid out, but the `-lib` option allows you to tell the compiler about additional directories containing `.dll` assemblies and `-r` allows you to reference a specific assembly. The compiler will build a `.exe` assembly by default; use `-target:library` or `-t:library` to build a `.dll` one instead. The `-help` option will give you a list of all options.

You can use whatever build system you prefer from the command line. If you need to process MSBuild project files, then `xbuild` can handle them, but `make`, `cmake`, `scons` work fine, too, and are probably preferable to editing `.sln` files in Vim. You may still have to figure out dependencies yourself if they aren't obvious and if you have a complex project with multiple assemblies (the compiler is fast enough that you can just recompile everything for small single-assembly projects).

Note that I am not using Mono for this myself, but primarily for command line projects on OS X/Linux, so the above may be missing some subtle details related to building mtouch-ready assemblies for iOS.